# How to emulate the interrupts mecanism on Linux

Tags: linux, embedded, interrupt, freertos

I am developing a program for a micro controller using FreeRTOS. My micro controller has a CAN driver and uses hardware interrupts. There is an interrupt fired when the CAN driver finished transmitting a CAN frame.

For simplicity I am developing and testing some part on Linux (Ubuntu 20). I am using socketCAN on Linux, with a virtual CAN port.

Is it possible to mimic the hardware interrupts on Linux ?

I was thinking to use the POSIX Signals, what do you think ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you considered [qemu](https://www.qemu.org) (depends on your target mcu)?

Comment: It does not seems to solve my problem. Besides, It is not supporting Cortex-R processors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The solution is to execute a task in parallel and call the function normally pointed by the interrupt vector.

While finding the solution I remarked that using POSIX signals between FreeRTOS tasks of the POSIX_GCC may lead to problem with linux system calls.
I also figured out that FreeRTOS tasks are monopolizing CPU time if they are used along with classical pthreads.